# Wordpress showing 404 page template for unpublished posts

Tags: page-template

When I open a URL that point to a post which is not published yet, wordpress shows a 404 page. But I want to show a meaningfull message to user that "this post is not published by admin, please contact admin to get it published"

How can I do this?

Edit: Is their any way i can get wordpress to run my single.php template instead of 404 template in my case?

Comment: Sorry for my asking, but how/why would one get to that page? I mean, how come anyone knows the link to an unpublished (and thus unmentioned/-linked) post?

Comment: @tf Referer from post preview. I get these each day.

Comment: Actually in my case user can submit posts from front end and receives link in email.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_status with a simple if statement inside of 404.php or single.php. 
I don't really know where it will work in that case, it's just an idea.